# Migrating WPF library from .NET Framework to .NET 6

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-6.0, .net-4.8

I'm currently migrating my WPF projects from .NET Framework 4.8 to .NET 6 using the .NET Upgrade Assistant as a base and then manually fixing the remaining problems.
All my projects have a shared set of libraries, one of this contains both standard classes and a few custom `UserControl`. When migrating this particular library to .NET 6 the frameworks referenced by this library are `Microsoft.NETCore.App` and `Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App`. The problem is when I try to use this library in another project I get the following warning:

> Warning    MSB3277 Found conflicts between different versions of "WindowsBase" that could not be resolved.
> There was a conflict between "WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" and "WindowsBase, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35".
> "WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" was chosen because it was primary and "WindowsBase, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" was not.

Looking at the WindowsBase referenced by the two frameworks referenced by the library I see that `Microsoft.NETCore.App` references WindowsBase v4.0.0.0 while `Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App` references WindowsBase v6.0.0.0.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Try to remove `WindowsBase` dependency and then add it again with correct version.

Comment: From Visual Studio I can't find a way to remove the dependency from the referenced frameworks. Maybe there's a way to do it manually?

Comment: [How to: Create and remove project dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-and-remove-project-dependencies?view=vs-2022)

Comment: In that menu you see  just the dependencies on other projects of the solution, not the ones on which the frameworks referenced by the project rely on

Comment: How does the project file of the project that doesn't compile look like?

Comment: The project does compile, this is only a warning. I haven't tested yet if the program works propertly, but it bothers me that it uses an old version of the WindowsBase library where it shouldn't. Anyway, what part of the csproj do you need? Since it is quite long.

Answer (score 1):

I met the exact issue as you when upgrading a csharp project from .Net framework to .Net6.

There are some dependencies under assemblies (such as `system` `system.xml`) which directed to the wrong framework path but can not be removed or modified. There was no much information about this issue on csdn so it really took me a while to find the root cause by trial and error, and finally it was the `WinFX.Targets` file imported in my csproj project file which brough these .net framework dependencies.

The `WinFX.Targets` file was imported by csproj before upgrading and the importing was deleted by upgrading. It was necessary for the project so I added it back without modification, which caused the MSB3277 build warning.

Comment: So you haven't find a solution either, do you? I switched to other projects so I don't know if the problem is still present in my project. I found someone telling that adding the tag `<UseWPF>true</UseWPF>` in the csproj file under the tag `PropertyGroup` solved the problem but I can't test it since I no longer have the original project.

Comment: @Ori my answer did resolve the MSB3277 build warnings in one of my projects. But later when I build other projects under the same solution I found more MSB3277 warnings which came with `C1001` internal error and could not be fixed by this way. I assumes when upgrading from .net framework to .net 6, many factors would cause this warning, and the developer has to fix it according to the projects

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in a solution containing a shared Razor Class Library (RCL), which is referenced by two projects: 1) .NET MAUI Blazor App (for desktop); and 2) Blazor Server App (for web). In my case, I made the mistake of adding **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting** directly to the RCL, which means I had to add **Microsoft.AspNetCore.App** as a framework (to the RCL).

Side note: **Microsoft.AspNetCore.App** should not be confused with **Microsoft.NETCore.App**. Razor Class Libraries *do* target the latter.

When I ran the web app, everything was fine because (as of the time of writing) Blazor Server Apps use **Microsoft.AspNetCore.App** as a framework (see in Visual Studio > Project > Dependencies > Frameworks). However, as I realized, the .NET MAUI Blazor App targets the frameworks **net7.0-windows**, **net7.0-maccatalyst**, etc.

I ended up creating an interface, which the RCL references, and registering framework-specific implementations in each app.

P.S., All of my projects target .NET 7.0.

Answer (score 0):

This warning disappeared after I added a FrameworkReference to `Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App` to the `.vcxproj` project file:

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid such problems, we explicitly disable binding redirects in .NET Core, net6, etc:

```
<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>false</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
<GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>false</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
```